# ComboBox showing many data

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a problem here. I want my combo `ComboBox` to list unique data but it appears multiple example 
[image]

In `FEB 1`, I have a one Purchase Order Number and it is repeated multiple times in `CounterChecking`

This is my code;

```
try
        {

            SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["POSdb"].ConnectionString);

            sc.Open();


            string strQry = "SELECT po_no"+
                " FROM CounterChecking";
            SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(strQry, sc);
            SqlDataReader dr = scmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("po_no", typeof(string));
            dt.Load(dr);

            cb_po_search.ValueMember = "po_no";
            cb_po_search.DisplayMember = "po_no";
            cb_po_search.DataSource = dt;

            sc.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `CounterChecking` table consists of multiple PO No's then your `sqlQry` should group based on the `po_no` column to get a unique list.

The query should be;

`sqlQry = "SELECT po_no"+
                " FROM CounterChecking GROUP BY po_no";`